# I cannot use alphanumeric keyboard in a input element when using the FullScreen API in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fullscreen

In Google Chrome, when I am using FullScreen API and I try to type in alphanumeric content in the input element it does not do anything. It works in Firefox.

Is their a workaround to this problem in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 6):

```
docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
```

check [this link](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/)

Content from link:

> **Full screen with key input**
>
> For security reasons, most keyboard inputs have been blocked in the fullscreen mode. However, in Google Chrome you can request keyboard support by calling the method with a flag:

```
docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
```

> This does not work in Safari, and the method won’t be called.
>
> With Firefox, we are discussing and looking into various ways of how we we could add keyboard input support without jeopardizing the end user’s security. One suggestion, that no one has implemented yet, is the requestFullscreenWithKeys method, which in turn would trigger certain notifications for the user.

Comment: Sorry for the time it took me to answer... For some reason it does not work on my Google Chrome.

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to your answer / a brief summary of the content within the external link?