# Forms don't allow text input when in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When You click the full-screen button using chrome on [this](http://jsbin.com/ayIHUpi/1) site the text input doesn't work properly, space works but text doesn't. The code that is used to make it full screen is

```
function launchFullScreen(element) {
    if (element.requestFullScreen) {
        element.requestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        element.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

and `onClick="launchFullScreen(document.documentElement);"`

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup?

Comment: Security conserns. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562148/i-cannot-use-alphanumeric-keyboard-in-a-input-element-when-using-the-fullscreen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at [this site](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/01/using-the-fullscreen-api-in-web-browsers/)

> Full screen with key input For security reasons, most keyboard inputs
>   have been blocked in the fullscreen mode. However, in Google Chrome
>   you can request keyboard support by calling the method with a flag:
>
> `docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);`
>
> This does not work in Safari, and the method won’t be called.
>
> With Firefox, we are discussing and looking into various ways of how
>   we we could add keyboard input support without jeopardizing the end
>   user’s security. One suggestion, that no one has implemented yet, is
>   the requestFullscreenWithKeys method, which in turn would trigger
>   certain notifications for the user.

More about this problem can read in [that older post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266897/cant-type-any-letters-or-numbers-in-text-inputs-in-fullscreen-mode-on-webkit-br)